# R - ggplot line color (using geom_line) doesn't change

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

When ploting 2 lines on one plot with ggplot(geom_line) the color of the line doesn't compre to the color that I set. I want the lines black and blue, but the outcome is red and blue. I tried it without (first code) and with (second) 'scale_color_manual', also tried with colour insted of color, with the same result:

fisrt code:

```
  ggplot(data=main_data) +
  # black plot
  geom_line(aes(x=vectors_growth_rate_with_predator, 
                y=disease_prevalnce_with_predator,
                color = "black")) + 
  # blue plot
  geom_line(aes(x=vectors_growth_rate_with_predator, 
                y=disease_prevalnce_without_predator,
                color = "blue"))
```

second code:

```
PrevVSGrowth = 
  ggplot(data=main_data) +
  # black plot
  geom_line(aes(x=vectors_growth_rate_with_predator, 
                y=disease_prevalnce_with_predator)) + 
  # blue plot
  geom_line(aes(x=vectors_growth_rate_with_predator, 
                y=disease_prevalnce_without_predator))

PrevVSGrowth + scale_color_manual(values=c(disease_prevalnce_with_predator= 'black',
                                           disease_prevalnce_without_predator = 'blue'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your first code should be

```
ggplot(data=main_data) +
# black plot
geom_line(aes(x=vectors_growth_rate_with_predator, 
              y=disease_prevalnce_with_predator),
          color = "black") + 
# blue plot
geom_line(aes(x=vectors_growth_rate_with_predator, 
              y=disease_prevalnce_without_predator),
          color = "blue")
```

You need to put `color` outside `aes()`.

For your second code you need to [reshape your data from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format). You can do this in many ways, the following should work for you.

```
library(tidyverse)
main_data <- main_data %>% 
               gather(key, value, c("disease_prevalnce_with_predator",
                                    "disease_prevalnce_without_predator")
PrevVSGrowth <- ggplot(data=main_data) +
 geom_line(aes(x=vectors_growth_rate_with_predator, 
               y=value,
               col = key))

PrevVSGrowth + 
scale_color_manual(values = c(disease_prevalnce_with_predator= 'black',
                              disease_prevalnce_without_predator = 'blue'))
```

---

In the first plot we **set** an aesthetic to a fixed value, in each call to `geom_line()`. This creates two new variables containing only the value "black" and "blue", respectively. In OP's example the values "black" and "blue" are then scaled to red and lightblue and a legend is added.

In the second plot we **map** the colour aesthetic to a variable (`key` in this example). This is usually the preferred way.