# How do i produce a legend title and labelling of ggplot + geom_point?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am struggling with generating a legend and its labels for my ggplot + geom_point.

The following is my code

```
# Create an index to hold values of m from 1 to 100
m_index <- (1:100)

# Creating data frames to store the correlations
data_frame_50 <- data.frame(prob_max_abs_cor_50)
data_frame_20 <- data.frame(prob_max_abs_cor_20)


library(ggplot2)




# Plot correlations using ggplot and geom_point 
ggplot() +
geom_point(data = data_frame_50, aes(x = m_index, y  = prob_max_abs_cor_50),  
 colour = 'red') +
geom_point(data = data_frame_20, aes(x = m_index, y = prob_max_abs_cor_20),
 colour = 'blue') +
labs(x = " Values of m  ", y = " Maximum Absolute Correlation ",
 title = "Dot plot of probability")
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R - ggplot line color (using geom\_line) doesn't change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48051905/r-ggplot-line-color-using-geom-line-doesnt-change)

Comment: I have tried running the code according to the link above but there is no change, instead the legend box disappeared

Comment: As others have stated, this is covered elsewhere. `ggplot2` works better if your data is in a single, long data frame. In your case, try:`df <- data.frame(m_index, prob_max_abs_cor_20, prob_max_abs_cor_50);
df_long <- gather(df, type, value, -m_index); ggplot(df_long, aes(x = m_index, y = value, colour = type)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "Values of m", y = " Maximum Absolute Correlation ",
       title = "Dot plot of probability")`

Comment: Yes the legend has appeared. how about renaming the legend labels? I changed type to legend and the labels at the side read prob_max_abs_cor_20 and prob_max_abs_cor_50. i would like to change it to n = 20 and n = 50 respectively